# Making a boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

I want to make a `boolean` numpy array in **cython** with the given size of another **numpy.array** but it raises an error message:

**CosmoTest.pyx**

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from libcpp cimport bool
x=np.array([[-0.3,1.2],[2.5,0.82],[0.61,-0.7]])
mask= np.ones_like(x,dtype=bool)
```

error:

```
        mask= np.ones_like(x,dtype=bool)
                                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

CosmoTest.pyx:318:39: 'bool' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
```

How should it be defined in cython?

**Update:**

```
cpdef np.ndarray arc( np.ndarray x):
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode='c'] out = np.zeros_like(x)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t,cast=True, ndim=1] mask = (x < 0.999).view(dtype=np.uint8)
    if mask.any():
        out[mask] = 0.5*np.log((1.+((1.-x[mask])/(x[mask]+1.))**0.5)/(1.-((1.-x[mask])/(x[mask]+1.))**0.5))/(1-x[mask]**2)**0.5

    cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t,cast=True, ndim=1] mask = (x > 1.001).view(dtype=np.uint8)
    if mask.any():
        out[mask] = np.arctan(((x[mask]-1.)/(x[mask]+1.))**0.5)/(x[mask]**2 - 1)**0.5

    cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t,cast=True , ndim=1] mask = ((x >= 0.999) & (x <= 1.001)).view(dtype=np.uint8)
    if mask.any():
        out[mask] = 5./6. - x[mask]/3.

    return out
```

**Error Message:**

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        if mask.any():
            out[mask] = 0.5*np.log((1.+((1.-x[mask])/(x[mask]+1.))**0.5)/(1.-((1.-x[mask])/(x[mask]+1.))**0.5))/(1-x[mask]**2)**0.5

        cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t,cast=True, ndim=1] mask = (x > 1.001).view(dtype=np.uint8)
        if mask.any():
            out[mask] = np.arctan(((x[mask]-1.)/(x[mask]+1.))**0.5)/(x[mask]**2 - 1)**0.5
                                                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

CosmoTest.pyx:9:55: local variable 'mask' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you change (the last line of) your code to

```
mask= np.ones_like(x,dtype=np.bool)
```

it will work (take `bool` from numpy rather than trying to use the lipcpp definition). However, actually statically typing boolean numpy arrays doesn't quite work currently (see [Passing a numpy pointer (dtype=np.bool) to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058744/passing-a-numpy-pointer-dtype-np-bool-to-c)).

The best way forward currently is to statically type them as

```
def f(np.ndarray[dtype=np.int8_t,ndim=1] x):
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype=np.int8_t,ndim=1] y
    y = np.ones_like(x,dtype=np.int8)
    return y.view(dtype=np.bool) # returns as boolean array
```

Internally numpy uses an 8 bit integer to store a bool, and thus you can just use `view` to reinterpret the array without copying.

If you had a boolean array and wanted to call `f` you'd do

```
mask = np.array([True,False,True])
f(mask.view(dtype=np.int8))
```

You could always write a small wrapper function as your public interface to `f` to do that reinterpretation automatically.

It's more fiddly than it needs be be, but it is possible to work with.

**Addition in response to comments**

The article I linked to suggested using `cast=True`:

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t,cast=True] mask = (x > 0.01)
```

This also works fine. Written in my approach that would be

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t] mask = (x > 0.01).view(dtype=np.uint8)
```

(i.e. no cast, but with a `view`). As far as I can tell there's no practical difference, so pick which one you think looks nicer.

**And edited to respond to additional issues**

The working code is below (I've checked and it compiles - I haven't checked to make sure it runs). You were getting compiler errors because you'd defined the type of `mask` multiple times. You're only allowed to use `cdef` once per variable per function, but having defined the type you can assign to it as often as you like.

```
cpdef np.ndarray arc( np.ndarray x):
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode='c'] out = np.zeros_like(x)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim=1] mask = (x < 0.999).view(dtype=np.uint8)
    if mask.any():
        out[mask] = 0.5*np.log((1.+((1.-x[mask])/(x[mask]+1.))**0.5)/(1.-((1.-x[mask])/(x[mask]+1.))**0.5))/(1-x[mask]**2)**0.5

    mask = (x > 1.001).view(dtype=np.uint8) # REMOVED cdef!
    if mask.any():
        out[mask] = np.arctan(((x[mask]-1.)/(x[mask]+1.))**0.5)/(x[mask]**2 - 1)**0.5

    mask = ((x >= 0.999) & (x <= 1.001)).view(dtype=np.uint8) # REMOVED cdef!
    if mask.any():
        out[mask] = 5./6. - x[mask]/3.

    return out
```

(I've also removed `cast=True` from the definition. This isn't important. You can either use that, or use `view(dtype=np.uint8)`. You can use both if you like, but it's more typing!)

Comment: Basically I want to do this operation and I am wondering how it should be done with your approach `cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8, cast=True] mask = (x > 0.01)`?

Comment: @Dalek The only thing you have wrong with the line you just quoted is you need to add a `_t` after `np.uint8` (i.e. `np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, cast=True]...`). The need to add `_t` when specifying numpy types in `cdef` statements is just an oddity of cython.

Comment: For reference, within Cython you can use the mask as is for logical indexing (i.e. `x[mask] = 10` works fine). If you pass the mask back to Python then do it as `return mask.view(dtype=np.bool)`

Comment: I am getting this error message by defining mask the way you suggested`cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8] mask = (x < 0.999).view(dtype=np.uint8)
                               ^
------------------------------------------------------------

CosmoTest.pyx:297:32: Invalid type.`

Comment: Moreover, when I define mask like this: `cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t] mask = (x < 0.999).view(dtype=np.uint8) ^ ------------------------------------------------------------ CosmoTest.pyx:297:13: Compiler crash in AnalyseExpressionsTransform` raised this error.

Comment: The latter version (`cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t]...`) is the right one and works for me (in a very simple test-case). I think this must just be a bug in Cython you're somehow triggering. If you're looking for something to change in the hope that it works then add `ndim=<number of dimensions>` to your square brackets, if you know that. Otherwise try the `cast=True` form and see if that works instead. However I don't think that's the real problem.

Comment: I really think this should work though, and you've just somehow upset Cython!

Comment: See updated answer... It wasn't a helpful error message, but it's easily fixed.